# how to create a program on python that can input a number from a user and classify it as either prime or composite

Tags: numbers

I'm stuck at a point where the computer has to check for all remainders of the number which has been given by the user. Am I supposed to use a For loop for this if yes then how?
Thank you.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division 

A few quick tests, , assuming the number is 10 or higher, if it ends with 0,2,4,5,6 or 8 it is not prime. Any that pass that test, try dividing that number by 2,3,5, 7 and 11, if all the results have decimal places, then it is prime. Any result that ends with X.0  is not prime (it was evenly divisible with no remainder)

Depending on how large the input number is, it may become impractical. In short, there is no single method that doesn't have some short coming as numbers get large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you need to use for loop, below function will give you how you can use for loop to check whether number is prime or not.

```
def prime(n):
    flag = 0
    for i in range(2,(n/2)+2):
        if n%i==0:
            flag = 1 
            return "composite"
    if flag==0:
        return "prime"
```

Comment: x=int(input("enter your number "))      
for y in range(2,x):
    if(x%y==0):            
        print("Not a prime")
        break
    if(x%y>0):
        print("Prime")
        break

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime_or_composite(num):
    div = 2
    while True:
        if num == div:
            print("It is a prime number!")
            break
        elif num % div = 0:
            print("It is a composite number!")
            break
        else:
            div += 1
```

This works if the input number is an integer bigger than 2.